# sqlitegen for data access code generation

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlitegen(http://code.google.com/p/sqlitegen/) plugin in eclipse for android. The documentation for using it is not so good. I have the following issues:

1) Downloaded the required plugins and put it into my Eclipse/Plugins folder and restarted eclipse.

2) I added the downloaded plugins to my project as referenced libraries.

When I build the project, sqlitegen doesn't generate the .java files for sql data access. Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/issues/detail?id=183

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in sqlite code generation I have a similar open source plugin that can generate Content Providers backed by Sqlite, its already quite powerful, but still a work in progress, I am at the stage of getting other people to try it out and make it better, check it out here, its part of a plugin called Mechanoid that is a set of DSL's for the rapid development of Android apps.

More info here:

http://robotoworks.github.com/mechanoid/

http://robotoworks.com/mechanoid-plugin/mechanoid-db/

Also check out the blog posts relating to Mechanoid DB:

http://robotoworks.com/category/technical/

Comment: I want to go in , where is that?

Comment: I just corrected the link and added more, look forward to your feedback!